# How to disable Windows Update in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

When I connect to the internet, Windows Update will be start.

I want to disable Windows Update on my machine.

Can I disable it from the registry? Is there other way to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel >System And Security >Windows Update
Click on the *Change Settings* in the Left panel
Select Never check for updates from the dropdown for *Important updates*
Click on Ok

Follow [this](http://www.techtalkz.com/windows-7/515869-windows-update-enable-disable-automatic-updates-windows-7-guide.html) link for a  screenshots on how to disable windows updates on Windows 7

Comment: Link only answers are not really useful, and expose the site to potential linkrot in the future. Can you transpose the main points to your answer?